# CIFAR-100: What is the difference between vehicles 1 and vehicles 2?

Tags: dataset, image-classification

The superclasses in the [CIFAR-100 dataset](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/cifar.html) are mutually exclusive and all but the vehicle ones are quite well defined by its label.

**Example:** It is very clear why bees belong to the superclass insects and none of the other superclasses.

This appears not to be the case for the two superclasses vehicles 1 and vehicles 2: The two appear not to be clearly separable if we ignore their subclass labels.

**Example:** It is not clear why pickup trucks belong to the category vehicles 1 and not vehicles 2.

Clearly, vehicles 1 vs. vehicles 2 are not distinguished by size, number of wheels, number of passengers, ….
Hence, my question is: **What distinguishes classes vehicles 1 and vehicles 2?**

As a reminder, these are the two vehicle-classes:

> **vehicles 1:**   bicycle, bus, motorcycle, pickup truck, train
>
> **vehicles 2:**   lawn-mower, rocket, streetcar, tank, tractor

Answer (score 1):

The difference between vehicles 1 and vehicles 2 is that vehicles 1 are more common and vehicles 2 are less common.

CIFAR-100 dataset super/coarse labels are not very rigorous. The [CIFAR-100 official documentation](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) points out flaws in their taxonomy:

> fruit and vegetables: apples, mushrooms, oranges, pears, sweet peppers
>   large carnivores: bear, leopard, lion, tiger, wolf
>   …
>   Yes, I know mushrooms aren't really fruit or vegetables and bears aren't really carnivores.

Comment: This distinction criteria appears to work quite fine, while I would still say that a streetcar is a very common vehicle.
Do you have any reference to that distinction between vehicles 1 and vehicles 2 or did you come up with it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own version of CIFAR 100 to do a CIFAR 10 Vs. CIFAR 100 experiment. Meaning that to a model trained on CIFAR 10, where it would learn images on Trucks, pickup Trucks are anomalous to it and can be used to measure OOD performance on class Trucks. So you can adjust the class labels of CIFAR 100 as it makes the most sense to test a CIFAR 10 trained model OOD performance.